# How to create a CheckBoxListFor extension method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I know there is a `ListBoxFor` extension method among the ASP.NET MVC Html helper extension methods, but I always thought that a checkbox list is more user-friendly than a list box.

There was a very convenient `CheckBoxList` control in good old WebForms, but obviously that is out of the picture now.

The question is, why is there no way in ASP.NET MVC to create a check box list? How can I write my own extension method that creates a check box list and behaves in a similar way `ListBoxFor` behaves?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is a strongly typed HtmlHelper for CheckBoxListFor that handles selected items as an array in your viewdata model. I chose not to wrapper the Html.CheckBox or Html.CheckBoxFor methods as I don't want the hidden "false" fields in my checkbox lists.

Please feel free to improve on this and repost :-)

```
//View

<%: Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.FreightTypeIds, FreightTypeMultiSelectList)  %>

//Controller

    public ActionResult SomeAction(int[] FreightTypeIds)
    {
       //...

       return View();
    }


//Extension
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression, MultiSelectList allOptions, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    ModelMetadata modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    // Derive property name for checkbox name
    string propertyName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(modelMetadata.PropertyName);

    // Get currently select values from the ViewData model
    IEnumerable<TProperty> list = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

    // Convert selected value list to a List<string> for easy manipulation
    IList<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

    if (list != null)
    {
        selectedValues = new List<TProperty>(list).ConvertAll<string>(delegate(TProperty i) { return i.ToString(); });
    }

    // Create div
    TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
    divTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

    // Add checkboxes
    foreach (SelectListItem item in allOptions)
    {
        divTag.InnerHtml += string.Format(
                                          "<div><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{1}_{2}\" " +
                                          "value=\"{2}\" {3} /><label for=\"{1}_{2}\">{4}</label></div>",
                                          propertyName,
                                          TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(propertyName),
                                          item.Value,
                                          selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty,
                                          item.Text);
    }

     return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for. Will try it once I get home.

Comment: With some modifications, I successfully made it to work as I wanted. Thank you very much for the code! :)

Comment: @RafaelSoares what kind of validation are you planning to do? that at least one has to be ticked or something similar?

Comment: @RafaelSoares - In situations like this I tend to use a hidden field e.g. "CheckboxChecked" with no initial value and a 'Required' validation message on it. Then I wire up some jquery to the checkboxes so that if one or more of the checkboxes is "checked" the value in the hidden field is set to true|yes|ok or anything else. If none are checked just remove the value from the hidden field and the validation should work.

Comment: If you have this nested inside an EditorFor it will not bind correctly.  I had to set the propertyName variable from htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(modelMetadata.PropertyName); Then use a sanitized id with TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId()

Answer (score 2):

I'm still experimenting but this seems to get along with the default binder and persists the user selections after post.. Hidden fields, really?? .. will this fly in html5 ? This feels crazy but I'd rather do this than hit my db for drop down lists and checkbox lists just because ModelState.IsValid is false..

```
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, List<SelectListItem> list, string ModelCollectionName)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (list != null)
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var l in list)
            {
                string collectionNameIndex = String.Format("{0}[{1}]", ModelCollectionName, i);

                var hiddenName = new TagBuilder("input");
                hiddenName.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "hidden"));
                hiddenName.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", String.Format("{0}.{1}", collectionNameIndex, "Text")));
                hiddenName.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", l.Text));

                var hiddenValue = new TagBuilder("input");
                hiddenValue.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "hidden"));
                hiddenValue.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", String.Format("{0}.{1}", collectionNameIndex, "Value")));
                hiddenValue.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", l.Value));

                var checkBoxTag = htmlHelper.CheckBox(String.Format("{0}.{1}", collectionNameIndex, "Selected"), l.Selected);

                var labelTag = new TagBuilder("label");
                labelTag.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("for", String.Format("{0}.{1}", collectionNameIndex, "Name")));
                labelTag.SetInnerText(l.Text);

                sb.Append(hiddenName);
                sb.Append(hiddenValue);
                sb.Append(checkBoxTag);
                sb.Append(labelTag);
                sb.Append("<br/>");

                i++;
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While Microsoft employees are probably the only ones that can answer why such helper method doesn't exist you could try:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel 
        { 
            Values = new[] { true, false, true, false }
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Values) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

As you can see `EditorFor` will handle everything that's needed.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but as I said, I'd like to have something similar to the behaviour of `ListBoxFor`.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? `ListBoxFor` generates `<select>` and accepts different types. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [CheckBoxList Helper for MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/10/checkboxlist-helper-for-mvc.aspx) article by Jeremiah Clark (unfortunately it's dated Nov 2008 and concerns MVC 1).

Comment: The article is good, but it is not written with strongly typed HTML helpers in mind.