# using CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a class Role as follows;

```
public enum Role
{                                            
    User1 = 1,
    User2 = 2,
    User3 = 3, 
    User4 = 4
}
```

I have the following codes in my model

```
public Role[] UserRoles { get; set; }
 User user = User.Load(1);
        UserRoles = user.Roles;
```

My question is as follows:
I want to have a checkbox for each Role and if Role == userRoles, the checkbox is true else false.  How can I use @HTml.CheckboxFor...Can I have an example please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difficulty in filling list while comparing arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804620/difficulty-in-filling-list-while-comparing-arrays)

Comment: ^^ "declined - Come back when its definite"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to come unstuck with hard-coded values if you are trying to create a checkbox list based on data from a DB.

You could try something like my CheckBoxListFor<> Extension:

[How to create a CheckBoxListFor extension method in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889397/how-to-create-a-checkboxlistfor-extension-method-in-asp-net-mvc/4057281#4057281)

Answer (score 4):

to use the CheckBoxFor you need a ViewModel with bool properties

```
public class YourVM
{                                            
  public bool[] Roles {get;set;}
}
```

and in the view

```
@model YourVM

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count(); i++) {
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Roles[i])
}
```

Comment: Isn`t there any more elegant way of doing this? I rather want it to be dynamic and not hard coded

Comment: @user281180 if you want to use the strongly typed CheckBoxFor you need a viewmodel with bool properties

Comment: any other means of achieveing the above using a more elegant method? I might not be using CheckBoxFor?

Comment: @user281180 do you try to achieve something like here? : http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/user (click on edit after on the button near roles)

Comment: Not really, I want to display all the Roles and if UserRoles contains any ofthe Role, the checkbox is checked

Comment: @user281180 you can make use of the listbinding, I've edited my answer

Comment: using the library from the link that I showed you, you can do this by @Html.LookupFor(o => o.Roles), but it's not checkboxes, it's a popup split into the selected items and available items, for the checkboxes to make shorter I guess you would have to create a helper

Comment: I have an idea of creating an array, but having difficulty in one part of it, See if you can helop pleasehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804620/difficulty-in-filling-list-while-comparing-arrays

Answer (score 0):

I answered this and your other question, on your other question.  There is no reason to make multiple questions for the same problem, you can edit your own questions.

[Difficulty in filling list while comparing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804620/difficulty-in-filling-list-while-comparing-arrays)