# Difficulty in filling list while comparing arrays

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In the following I want to use GetUsersRole but having difficulty with the part shown.  I want to compare the Roles values with usersRole, and if Role==usersRole, then UserRole = true, else false.

basically I want to have somehing like this as my result :

user1: true

user2:false

user 3: false

user4: true

depending on usersRole

Class Role

```
public enum Role
{                                            
    User1 = 1,
    User2= 2,
    User3= 3, 
    User4= 4
}
```

I am having a class

```
private class UserRoleModel
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

and a method

```
public Role[] UserRoles { get; set; }  
private static UserRoleModel[] GetUsersRole(Role[]usersRole)
{
    List<UserRoleModel> rolesList = new List<UserRoleModel>();
    string[] Roles;
    Roles = new string[] { Role.user1.ToString(), Role.User2.ToString(), 
              Role.user3.ToString(), Role.user4.ToString() };
    foreach (var item in Roles)
    {
        rolesList.Add(new UserRoleModel
        {
            Role = item,
            *UserRole = usersRole.Contains(item)* ////difficulty here
        });
    }
    return rolesList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this code makes no sense to me at all. What is `Role`, as in `Role.user1.ToString()`, and where does it come from? What is the actual objective of this code, it seems way too complex and that usually indicates to me that I've made a wrong turn.

Comment: Hi, may I know what's wrong with the code you've specified? does it not compile successfully? Also, the code does not quite make sense, esp. the part of Role.user1.toString(), and please provide the acceptable set of userRoles (maybe as an enum or something). Thanks!

Comment: I have missed this part, I am having a class Role as explained abve

Comment: can i know the Exception you are getting...

Comment: I am not having an exception, rather, don`t know how to compare and having error message as follows:Error 1 API.Role[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into this problem because you are turning the `Role` values into strings when you don’t actually need a string. Move the `ToString()` to where you actually need it:

```
public Role[] UserRoles { get; set; }  
private static UserRoleModel[] GetUsersRole(Role[]usersRole)
{
    List<UserRoleModel> rolesList = new List<UserRoleModel>();

    Role[] roles = (Role[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role));

    // or if you need the specific three values like in your example:
    // Role[] roles = new Role[] { Role.User1, Role.User2, Role.User3, Role.User4 };

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        rolesList.Add(new UserRoleModel
        {
            Role = role.ToString(),
            UserRole = usersRole.Contains(role)
        });
    }
    return rolesList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check last Update for correct answer**

I dont understand what you are trying to do. But from the code shown in your question, i can see that u are Calling Contains method

```
userRole.Contains(item);
```

and i am assuming that you are trying to find  the `item` in array of `Roles` But in the context the argument you took `userRole` is not an Array. To correct instead of :

```
private static UserRoleModel[] GetUsersRole(Role usersRole)
```

you should write:

```
private static UserRoleModel[] GetUsersRole(Role[] usersRole)
```

---

### Update

Ok i get it.. The problem is that in Contains methofd you are searching by passing a `String` where as the array contains values of Type Role.

**So the question is how to find a Enum Instance in an Array of Enum Instances from a string representation of Enum Instance**

Normally you can only search by the Type of the Items  in the Array but here you have a string Representation so something like this can be done:

create a function:

```
public Role GetRole(string rolestring)
{
     Role result; 
     foreach(string rolename in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Role)))
     {
       if(rolename == rolestring)
       {
           try 
           {
             result = (Role) Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), rolename); 
           }
           catch(ArgumentException e)
           {
                 //Most unlikely we ever enter this catch s we know for sure we have role
                 //Process if role not found
                 throw;
           }
       }
     }
     return result;
}
```

then in your code

```
UserRole = usersRole.Contains(GetRole(item));
```

---

### Update

**There is no Contains Method in Type Array**

Ok i get it.. The problem is  Contains method as there is no such method as Contains for Type Arrays instead its for Type `List<T>`

For arrays we have [`Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be.aspx) which takes a `Predicate` as an argument to search and return `bool`.

Use it like as follows:

```
//just to be sure correct value is captured everytime
string copy = item;
//Predicate is in System.Predicate<T>
Predicate<string> predicate = itemtocheck => {   
       itemtocheck == copy;
   };
UserRole = Array.Exists(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Role)), predicate);
```

---

My First update was correct but then i didn't notices that array dont have method Contains. Check my last update correct answer
Hope it helps

Comment: I have modified it, indeed I am passing an array as argument

Comment: oh!! you accepted my answer even before i gave you correct answer.. well Check out my last update for Correct Solution. I have not deleted my previous Update to let people see what mistake i did before...

Answer (score 0):

Between this and your previous question, I think I can figure out what you are trying to do.

First off, if your users can be in multiple roles, you'll want your roles enumeration to be decorated with the [`[Flags]`](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/01/19/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum.aspx) attribute.  I'm assuming this is what you want since you're using check boxes and not a radio selector.

Next, to dynamically get the names for the `Roles`, you'll want to use something more like [`[Enum.GetNames(enum)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx).  If you'd like something better for a description than the name of the value in the enum, you can google for a [`GetDescription`](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/01/19/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum.aspx) function pretty easily and then apply a `[Description(...)]` attribute to each one.

You will also want to write an `enum.HasFlag(MyEnum.ValueToCheckAgainst)` extension function ([or use the one built in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)) to determine if the checkbox is checked or not.

Also, @Shekhar_Pro's answer is also useful because you'll want your function to only take a single Role, not an array of them to generate the list of `UserRoleModel`s.  You will then call this function for each user you want to display.

And the last part, turning those check boxes back into a `Role` value, you'll have to do that manually.  Write a function which takes an array of `Role` values and AND's them all together (after you make it a legitimate flags enum).  Then just return the result.  If you want something more "elegant" than that, you'll probably just want to make that function an extension on whatever you think should output those values (like your view model).

Answer (score 0):

```
*UserRole = usersRole.Contains(item)* ////difficulty here
```

Change this to:

```
UserRole = false;
foreach(Role r in usersRole)
{
    if(r == item)
    {
        UserRole = true;
        break;
    }
}
```