# Trouble hydrating a Model with a Model in MVC 3 on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have 2 model classes similar to:

```
class DependenciesModel{
    List<int> DependencyComponentIDs { get; set; }
}

class ComponentModel{
    int ComponentID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    DependenciesModel Dependencies { get; set; }
}
```

The view uses looks something like this:

```
@model ComponentModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComponentID)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dependencies</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Dependencies, "DependencyEdit")</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And an editor template DependencyEdit.cshtml in the EditorTemplates folder:

```
@model DependenciesModel

// There is more to this but I'm simplifying to get to the point
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.DependencyComponentIDs)
```

I see the values being posted back in Fiddler, but in the controller the `Dependencies` property is empty.

The interesting part is that the posted field values are just `DependencyComponentIDs` without any indication that they are part of the `Dependencies` property

I've split the dependency list into a separate Model because there's a lot of management code in it that creates a good separation of concerns.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with separating out address information into a separate class for better code management.  in the end, I had to do a little more work to get it to return back and store in the object.

In your DependencyEdit.cshtml, try something like this

@model DependenciesModel

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DependencyComponentIDs.Count; i++) {
     @Html.CheckBox(String.Format("Dependencies.DependencyComponentIDs[{0}]", i), false, new{ value = Model.Dependencies.DependencyComponentIDs[i] })
}
```

This isn't a great solution, but it's done the trick for me.  You may want to also check out: [How to create a CheckBoxListFor extension method in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889397/how-to-create-a-checkboxlistfor-extension-method-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: I actually took this one [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension) and have been tweaking it

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember having a similar problem. could you try specifiying the Id explicilty for the dependencies control with either x.y or x_y where x is the wrapper class and y is the property? If not I'll check how I did it.