# How do I set up a check box with ASP MVC in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following class:

```
   public class City {  
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public bool CityValid { get; set; }
   }
```

I know how to set up the name but how can I set up the CityValid field so it acts like a checkbox. I'd like to do this without using HTML helpers.

Comment: could you just explain the reason of "without htmlHelpers" ? This looks quite weird...

Comment: I have some more logic that I want to fit around things. For example I'll do this in a loop and add different names to the checkboxes. checkbox_1 etc. This is the reason I wanted to do it without the helpers. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider using something like this if you have a list of checkboxes http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057281/491950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use helpers, you would use a normal HTML input tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CityValid" name="CityValid" value="@Model.CityValid" />
<input type="hidden" id="CityValue_Hidden" name="CityValid" value="false" />
```

The name attribute has to match your property name so that the model binder will pick it up correctly when you post back to the server.

When you use the helpers, something similar to the above markup will be generated. The hidden field is there so that a value is *always* sent with the form post data, regardless of whether you check the box or not (if you leave the box unchecked, no value gets sent by default, not even a 'false').

However, unless you're doing something really weird, I'd recommend you stick to using the helpers. Either:

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.CityValid)
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CityValid)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view you could use the `EditorFor` helper:

```
@model City
...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CityValid)
```

The default editor template for a boolean field generates a checkbox.

Comment: Even though it's a strange request, she mentioned without HTML helpers

Comment: I think that *without HTML helpers* she/he meant *without using the Html.CheckBoxFor helper*.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create it with a HTML-helper, look at the markup that gets created when running the page, and then recreate that markup...