# MVC 4, Checkbox list and me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-4

Morning all.

I can see this has been discussed elsewhere but was wondering if anything had change or things made simpler in MVC 4 for simpletons like me?!

**Scenario**

I have the following,edited, **model**:

```
public class CorporateDetails
{

    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int CorporateDetailId { get; set; }

    public int? EmsId { get; set; }
    public string EmsName { get; set; }

    public virtual EmsType EmsType { get; set; }
}

public class EmsType
{
    [Key]
    public int? EmsId { get; set; }
    public string EmsName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmsType> EmsTypes { get; set; }
}
```

With the following standard create **view**:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>CorporateDetails</legend>



    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmsId, "EmsType")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("EmsId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmsId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmsName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmsName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmsName)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

This gives me, out of the box, a beautiful drop down list a la [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx)

Now my real question is this - how can I effectively convert this drop down box to what will effectively be a multi select,checkbox list?

Again, apologies for going over trodden ground but I was just testing the water to see if any updates have occurred.

Please note, first MVC project so go gently, I'm feeling very thick again :'(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right ok, I have got it sorted - hurrah! As you can see from the comments, there were a few issues that came up but please find below the complete solution which DOES work :D

**Model**

```
 public class CorporateDetails
    {

        public Guid? Id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int CorporateDetailId { get; set; }

        public int[] EmsId { get; set; }

        }

    public class EmsType
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmsId { get; set; }
        public string EmsName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmsType> EmsTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CorporateDetails corporatedetails = new CorporateDetails();
        ViewBag.EmsId = new MultiSelectList(db.EmsTypes, "EmsId", "EmsName");
        return View(corporatedetails);
    }
```

**Extension** (placed in a folder in the root of the project)

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty[]>> expression, MultiSelectList multiSelectList, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        //Derive property name for checkbox name
        MemberExpression body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        string propertyName = body.Member.Name;

        //Get currently select values from the ViewData model
        TProperty[] list = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

        //Convert selected value list to a List<string> for easy manipulation
        List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

        if (list != null)
        {
            selectedValues = new List<TProperty>(list).ConvertAll<string>(delegate(TProperty i) { return i.ToString(); });
        }

        //Create div
        TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        divTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

        //Add checkboxes
        foreach (SelectListItem item in multiSelectList)
        {
            divTag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" " +
                                                "value=\"{1}\" {2} /><label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}</label></div>",
                                                propertyName,
                                                item.Value,
                                                selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",
                                                item.Text);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString());
    }
```

**Extension registered in web config of the Views**

```
 <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyProject.Extensions" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

**View**

```
@model Valpak.Websites.HealthChecker.Models.CorporateDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CorporateDetails</legend>

           <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.EmsId, (MultiSelectList) ViewBag.EmsId)
          </div>          
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Which gives me a lovely list of check boxes. Hurrah!

Thanks Darin for your help, I've marked this as the answer but +50 for your time and effort.

Comment: Really helpful, but it'd be even better if validation was included. Currently all my text boxes get a red border if there's a validation problem, do you have any idea how to include that feature?

Answer (score 5):

Nice solution -

Just for others reference - I, like you, had run into a need for a checkboxlist - I have been using this here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-a-missing-MVC-extension

It works great... very well written - hope this can help someone.

Loren

Answer (score 2):

No changes occurred in ASP.NET MVC 4 RC in this aspect and are unlikely to occur when it hits RTM.

But you could still [implement a custom helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219146/29407) to achieve that. And you could even improve this helper so that it takes a lambda expression as first argument instead of a string in order to have strongly typed version.

And if you are not using enums here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057281/29407).

Comment: Thanks Darin - with the extension exmaple, should I just add that as an anywhere in my project or specifically in with the views? (Apologies for the stupid question, see earlier "first MVC project" footnote)

Comment: You could create an `Extensions` folder and have a `HtmlExtensions.cs` class inside in which you will declare them.

Comment: Sorry Darin - me again :'( 

I've implemented this but receiving a nasty error:


CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Models.CorporateDetails>' has no applicable method named 'CheckBoxListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

I've tried adding @using MvcHtmlHelpers; (my helper) to the view itself but got stuck. 

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling it? I guess you are using `ViewBag` or something?

Comment: Exactly - 

ViewBag.EmsTypeId = new SelectList(db.EmsTypes, "EmsTypeId", "EmsTypeName");

Comment: How are you calling the helper in the view? You need to cast any dynamic ViewBag to the underlying type. Yeah, I know that sucks. But that's because you are using `ViewBag`. The whole thing sucks. You should use view models instead.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't understand:

 @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.EmsId, ViewBag.EmsId)

Comment: It's the second argument: you need to cast it to the underlying type because you cannot invoke extension methods on dynamic types: `@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.EmsId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmsId)`

Comment: Wow I suck big time at this.

So, I've moved forward but now got a lovely:


CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Extensions.HtmlHelper.CheckBoxListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty[]>>, System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: By the way, beers on me Darin :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13062/discussion-between-ricardo-deano-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass selected value to MultiSelected (parameter #4)

```
ViewBag.VfonctionIds = new MultiSelectList(db.tbIntervenantFonctionTypes, "intervenantFonctionType_id", "Nom", fonctionSelected);
```

Change the Helper to

```
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty[]>> expression, MultiSelectList multiSelectList, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        //Derive property name for checkbox name
        MemberExpression body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        string propertyName = body.Member.Name;

        //Create div
        TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        divTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

        //Add checkboxes
        foreach (SelectListItem item in multiSelectList)
        {
            divTag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" " +
                                                "value=\"{1}\" {2} /><label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}</label></div>",
                                                propertyName,
                                                item.Value,
                                                (item.Selected) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",                                                    
                                                item.Text);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString());
    }
```