# MVC, CheckboxList extension html helper..further issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-4

Good afternoon

I'm hoping this is going to be nice and a simple f**k up by myself but I've gone in deep and currently can't swim.

Ok, previously I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204464/mvc-4-checkbox-list-and-me) question and as such I have implemented the following:

**Model**

```
 public class CorporateDetails
{

    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int CorporateDetailId { get; set; }


    public int? EmsId { get; set; }
    public string EmsName { get; set; }

    public virtual EmsType EmsType { get; set; }
}

public class EmsType
{
    [Key]
    public int? EmsId { get; set; }
    public string EmsName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmsType> EmsTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.EmsId = new MultiSelectList(db.EmsTypes, "EmsId", "EmsName");
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>CorporateDetails</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmsId, "EmsType")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("EmsId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmsId)
    </div>
<div class="editor-label">

        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.EmsId, (MultiSelectList) ViewBag.EmsId)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Where this CheckBoxListFor uses the following **extension**:

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{
    //Extension
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty[]>> expression, MultiSelectList multiSelectList, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        //Derive property name for checkbox name
        MemberExpression body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        string propertyName = body.Member.Name;

        //Get currently select values from the ViewData model
        TProperty[] list = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

        //Convert selected value list to a List<string> for easy manipulation
        List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

        if (list != null)
        {
            selectedValues = new List<TProperty>(list).ConvertAll<string>(delegate(TProperty i) { return i.ToString(); });
        }

        //Create div
        TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        divTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

        //Add checkboxes
        foreach (SelectListItem item in multiSelectList)
        {
            divTag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" " +
                                                "value=\"{1}\" {2} /><label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}</label></div>",
                                                propertyName,
                                                item.Value,
                                                selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",
                                                item.Text);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString());
    }
}
```

So **what's the problem?**

Well when I run it I get a nasty error telling me:

> "CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'Extensions.HtmlHelper.CheckBoxListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList, object)' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong as I'm going round in circles and not sure what I have missed.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this here is that my original EmsId is a  nullable int and not an int array as required and hence the error.

Please refer to my answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204464/mvc-4-checkbox-list-and-me) for a full explanation of how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo,

I have shared some of my own MVC helpers on GitHub. Please feel free to browse & use the code as needed. One of the items in the project is a CheckBoxListItemFor helper, it was created specifically to create checkbox lists. Look under InputExtensions.cs

https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/EJC.UIExtensions/tree/master/EJC.UIExtensions/Html