# Foreach ViewModel with nested classes to update Checkbox List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I need to update a list of checkboxes based on the following ViewModel:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class MemberProfileListViewModel
    {
        public IList<MemberProfileDetailViewModel> MemberProfileDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class MemberProfileDetailViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model ViewModels.MemberProfileListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <fieldset>

    @foreach (var item in ??????)
    {
        <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(????)</p>
    }
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

The Controller:

```
    public virtual ActionResult EditProfiles()
    {
        var memberProfileListDto = _memberProfileService.ListByMember(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

        var memberProfileListViewModel = Mapper.Map<MemberProfileListDto, MemberProfileListViewModel>(memberProfileListDto);

        return View(memberProfileListViewModel);
    }
```

How do I make the list of the checkboxes with the Id to make the update back to the controller?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889397/#4057281

Comment: @Jerad ok, I will try to understand, be it looks a little complex for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `foreach` is not supported in this context. Try using `for` construct,

```
@for (int i=0; i < blah.count; i++ )
{
    <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.blah[i].foo)</p>
}
```